# Pulling hostname from TNS entry

Tags: sed

I am working on a script that will need to determine which node a db being used by a local app is running on.  I've been trying to use this as a chance to force myself to learn awk/sed and have a test script to test the statements.  It's working off a copy of the tnsnames.ora file I have moved to the home folder the script is located in.
Here is a valid tnsnames.ora stanza:

```
(
   DESCRIPTION = (
   ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP) (Host=iplab)(Port=1521))
   ) 
   (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=spurs1)) 
)
```

After doing some research and getting the awk expression to pull the tns entry to $host I came up with the below script but it doesn't seem to work.

```
#!/bin/ksh
db=spurs

host=$(awk -v db=$db "/${db}/ {for(i=1; i<=5; i++) {getline; print}}" tnsnames.ora)
echo $host
host= $host | sed 's/Host\s=\s\([a-z]+[0-9]?\)/\1/'
echo $host
```

When I run it the awk statement I get the following:

```
(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP) (Host=hostname)(Port=1521))) (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=spurs1)) )
./tns.ksh: line 6: (DESCRIPTION: not found
(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP) (Host=hostname)(Port=1521))) (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=spurs1)) )
```

From what I have seen reading tutorials and forums I think sed is setup correctly and should be setting $host to one or more lowercase letters followed by 0 or 1 numbers after Host = .  Since (DESCRIPTION is the start of $host before and after the sed statement I'm not sure how it isn't finding it, an

Comment: your error is due go the space after `host=` -- you wanted `host=$(echo "$host" | sed ...)`

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:
`tnsping $db | grep HOST | cut -d\  -f 14 | sed 's/).*//g'`

Answer (score 0):

On my system I can use this to get the host as long as the host name doesn't have an equals sign (or the actual literal word HOST in the name of the host):

echo $TNS_STRING | sed 's/.*HOST//g' | sed 's/).*//g' | sed 's/=//g' | sed 's/\s*//g'

Answer (score 0):

Your value for $host is likely a multiline value, so you need to quote it anyplace you use it, i.e.

```
host=$(awk -v db=$db "/${db}/ {for(i=1; i<=5; i++) {getline; print}}" tnsnames.ora)
echo "$host"
```

You also need to capture the output (using command-substitution) via `$(...)`

```
host=$(echo "$host" | sed 's/Host\s=\s\([a-z]+[0-9]?\)/\1/')
echo "$host"
```

(and echo it), so it can be processed by `sed`

**Revise**

```
host=$(echo $host | sed 's/.*Host=//; s/).*$//)
echo "$host"
```

I've switched back to just `$host`, without the dbl-quotes, as you don't want the linebreaks in the data. Now it is all one big string, and the regex, strips every upto `host=`, and then strips everything after the first remaining `)` char.

If you still get error messages, I don't have access to a tnsnames.ora record, so please edit your query to include a valid record.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I ran the updates you suggested and it didn't error, however both the echo back the full tns entry still. Here is a valid tnsnames.ora stanza: (DESCRIPTION =
  (ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)
    (Host=iplab)(Port=1521)))
  (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=spurs1))
 )

Comment: @user1401967 : I've edited you question to include the stanza, but I'm not certain that is correct format. See revisions in msg.

Comment: @user1401967 : I've got to leave for the day and won't get to look at this again until tomorrow. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

you may be better relying on the output of `tnsping` instead of parsing the  file: tnsping appears to emit the description on one line:

```
host=$(
  tnsping $db | while read line; do
    if [[ "$line" == *HOST* ]]; then
      s=${line#*HOST=}; s=${s%%)*}; echo "$s"; break
    fi
  done
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
db=spurs
host=$(sed '/^(/,/^)/!d;/^(/{h;d};H;/^)/!d;g;/'"$db"'/!d;s/.*Host=\([^)]*\).*/\1/' tnsnames.ora)
```

Answer (score -2):

Tested Code:

```
OIFS=$IFS;
IFS="(";
tns=`tnsping TNS_ALIAS`
tns_arr=($tns);
tns_info=(`(for ((i=0; i<${#tns_arr[@]}; ++i)); do  echo "${tns_arr[$i]/)/}"; done)| grep 'HOST\|PORT'|sed 's/)//g'|sed 's/ //g'`)
for ((i=0; i<${#tns_info[@]}; ++i)); do eval "export ${tns_info[$i]}"; done
echo "host:" $HOST
echo "port:" $PORT
IFS=$OIFS;
```